# Difference between current visit and contact

Tags: rules-engine

What's the difference between current visit and contact in the Sitecore rule engine? From the description, it sounds like

1. Current visit is based on the current user session's interaction
2. Current contact is based on the contact's lifetime interaction

Is this understanding correct?

[image: Rules Engine]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right.

`Current **visit**` is for the current interaction. Whatever happened during your current visit will be used to find the best matching pattern.

`Current **contact**` is for the overall values gathered in all the contact interactions. From what I remember (but DO double check it) current visit values are not included when calculating this one.

Comment: You are right that `contact` only includes what is in the behavioral cache and doesn't include the current session.